# Angular 8: Not getting the state value in required format using routerLink and state

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using angular 8

I use the following code to pass data when route to child component

```
<a routerLink="./publishedbook" state="{ id:1 , name:'Two States'}">Two States</a>
```

and try to get state value using the following code

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.location.getState());
    console.log(history.state);
    }
```

the console show

```
{0: "{", 1: " ", 2: "i", 3: "d", 4: ":", 5: "1", 6: " ", 7: ",", 8: " ", 9: "n", 10: "a", 11: "m", 12: "e", 13: ":", 14: "'", 15: "T", 16: "w", 17: "o", 18: " ", 19: "S", 20: "t", 21: "a", 22: "t", 23: "e", 24: "s", 25: "'", 26: "}", navigationId: 3}
{0: "{", 1: " ", 2: "i", 3: "d", 4: ":", 5: "1", 6: " ", 7: ",", 8: " ", 9: "n", 10: "a", 11: "m", 12: "e", 13: ":", 14: "'", 15: "T", 16: "w", 17: "o", 18: " ", 19: "S", 20: "t", 21: "a", 22: "t", 23: "e", 24: "s", 25: "'", 26: "}", navigationId: 3}
```

How the get the value in json format like

```
{ id:1 , name:'Two States' }
```

or in Object with the properties ->id and name have the respective values.

Comment: In order to pass data to the child component via an anchor tag, the data must either be included in the URL or a service that both the parent and child component can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose `state` property in brackets (Input property binding)

```
<a routerLink="./publishedbook" [state]="{ id:1 , name:'Two States'}">Two States</a>
```

In the activated component, you need to subscribe to `activatedRoute.paramMap`

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(()=> {
      console.log(window.history.state)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use *property binding* to send the state:

```html
<a routerLink="/publishedbook" [state]="{id: 1, name: 'Two States'}">
 /publishedbook
</a>
```

After that, capture your data object as follows:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  data: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data', data);
        this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Find a running example here: https://angular-routerlink-state-example.stackblitz.io